# Working with a discriminated Union-type instead of optional properties

Tags: typescript

I'm currently in the process of rewriting a JavaScript codebase into Typescript. I've discovered that the data in a function is defined like MyProps below:

```
interface MyProps {
  type: string;
  foo?: unknown;
  bar?: unknown;
  someCommonProps: unknown;
}
```

The usage has been like this:

```
const myFunction = (props: MyProps) => {
  const { type, foo, bar, someCommonProps } = props;
  if (foo) {
    //Do something
  }
  if (bar) {
    //Do something else
  }
};
```

By further investigation I see that the interfaces/types could be defined more precisely like this:

```
interface Foo {
  type: "a" | "b" | "c";
  foo: unknown;
}

interface Bar {
  type: "d" | "e" | "f";
  bar: unknown;
}

type FooBar = Foo|Bar;

type MyProps = FooBar & {
  someCommonProps: unknown;
}
```

But by assigning the new MyProps to props, I will get an error on the first line of myFunction: Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'MyProps'. And similar with 'bar'. What is the best way to handle this without rewriting in a way that may introduce bugs?

Answer (score 1):

With classes you can do this this way:

```
class Foo {
    type: 'a' | 'b' | 'c';
    foo: unknown;
}

class Bar {
    type: 'd' | 'e' | 'f';
    bar: unknown;
}

type FooBar = Foo | Bar;

type MyProps = FooBar & {
    someCommonProps: unknown;
};

const myFunction = (props: MyProps) => {
    if (props instanceof Foo) {
        // Do something
        console.log(props.someCommonProps);
    }
    if (props instanceof Bar) {
        // Do something else
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If your tags are string unions, you can use `switch(props.type)` and enumerate all values in the cases:

```
const myFunction = (props: MyProps) => {
  switch (props.type) {
    case 'a': case 'b': case 'c':
      let x = props.foo;
      break;
    case 'd': case 'e': case 'f':
      let y = props.bar;
      break;
  }
};
```

This can be tedious in the long run, here's one possible way to automate:

```
let FooTag = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const;

interface Foo2 {
  type: typeof FooTag[number];
  foo: unknown;
}

function isFoo2(x: Foo2 | Bar2): x is Foo2 {
  return (FooTag as readonly string[]).indexOf(x.type) >= 0;
}
...

const myFunction2 = (props: MyProps2) => {
  if (isFoo2(props)) {
    let x = props.foo;
  }
  if (isBar2(props)) {
    let x = props.bar;
  }
```

[Play](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#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-UxBo8ldX2bqHqwxJNgKTpFkOR5AMRTIEIJSSOUchyKqNR1A0Cbzr+CyYn0oQ-sMbhjH6wAWh0yapl0mKDGsdwoq8GLLN8oKyAQpGdIuQFUYUNGGgQ4pvB4HxYjiLHutwQA)

Answer (score 0):

While not as elegant, I think this is the easiest way achieve this:

```
const myFunction = (props: MyProps) => {
  const { type, someCommonProps } = props;
  const foo = 'foo' in props ? props.foo : undefined;
  const bar = 'bar' in props ? props.bar : undefined;
  if (foo) {
    //Do something
  }
  if (bar) {
    //Do something else
  }
};
```

Also consider if you can do something like this:

```
const foobar = 'foo' in props ? props.foo : props.bar;
```